# How to check Image name in folder and rename it?

Tags: php, file, csv

I have a csv file with image name and Prefix for image and I want to add prefix in that image name and rename it and move it to another directory.

```
<?php 


$fullpath = '/var/www/html/john/Source/01-00228.jpg';
$additional = '3D_Perception_';

while (file_exists($fullpath)) {
    $info = pathinfo($fullpath);
    $fullpath = $info['dirname'] . '/' . $additional
              . $info['filename'] 
        . '.' . $info['extension'];
echo $fullpath ;
}

?>
```

Here Image file is store in `Source`  Directory I want to rename it with some prefix and move it other directory like `Destination`

Please help me out to find solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $source_directory = '/var/www/html/john/Source/';
  $dest_directory = '/var/www/html/john/Source/'; // Assuming you'll change it
  $filename = '01-00228.jpg';
  $prefix = '3D_Perception_';

  $file = $source_directory . $filename;
  $dest_file = $dest_directory . $prefix . $filename;

  if (file_exists($file)) {
    if (copy($file, $dest_file)) {
      unlink($file); // Deleting source file.

      var_dump(pathinfo($dest_file)); // Dump dest file infos, replace it with wathever you want to do.
    } else {
      // if copy doesn't work, do something.
    }
  }
?>
```

Try this, and take care about my comments. ;)